# How to move Folder of Flutter Project to another drive safely?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

My Operating System is Linux Fedora 38.
I'm using:

- android studio 2022.3.1 .
- code 1.82.2 .
- Flutter 3.13.0 .
- Dart 3.1.0 .

My **problem** is shown when:

- i **move** folder of flutter project to another place in the same hard drive or to another driver , or
- when i **rename** the project.

Now i want to do that safely without facing a lot of problems.

i want to move floder of any project to another place without problem .

Answer (score 1):

If you move only necessary folders and files you will not have to face many issues.

Do not move the IDE folders like *.idea/* do not move *build/* or *dart_tool/* folders.

Check the flutter .gitignore https://gist.github.com/dileepabandara/43f37affb84650a7e59ff04204c44aa8 and ignore the folders and files listed there, everything should work fine no matter the device or the operating system.

Comment: The problem is when i move to another system for example 
from linux mint to fedora 
the mount point of linux mint in /media/username
but in fedora in /run/media/username